# be to + verb vs be going to + verb

Tags: grammar

e.g 
1)They are to make an announcement today.
2)They are going to make an announcement today.

Hi all, my question is that What is the different between these two sentence?
What is the different between "are to make" and "are going to make"?

Comment: They do not mean the same thing; *going* is not there for nothing. Please visit [ell.se] Good Luck.

Comment: @Kris: they do mean the same thing, as near as dammit. (1) has more of an official air to it, whereas (2) might be just an opinion; but apart from that, I see no difference.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware, there isn't much of a difference between the two, and no research done has suggested there is a difference. Both are a future tense sentence, though perhaps one is a near future tense, and one is just a normal future, similar to French grammar?

Answer (score 1):

They both mean the same. The only difference is:

1. I am to go there. : when used it is less likely you will be doing it soon.
2. I am going to do it: it stresses that i am about to do it now.